# Access 2007 - Why won't Access work on workspaces/web folders?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, workspace, web-folders

So if I try to take an Access database that currently resides on a network shared drive (or try to create a brand new one for that matter) on a web folder of a "workspace", why won't it work? I have read, write modify permissions on the folder I am trying to add it to, however I can errors, and it won't recognize the file type (.accdb or .mdb gets made .unk).

Could someone just explain the logic to me of why this doesn't work?

**EDIT:** So I guess I should include that on the shared drive there is a folder that houses the access front end file, and another folder within this folder that houses the BE tables file. I tried to reproduce what it one the shared drive in the web folder. I cannot even get the .mdb portion to work unless it's downloaded locally to my computer.

Comment: Does your workspace/web-folder get mapped to an actual drive letter?  If not, that would be why...

Comment: I don't really know what workspaces/web folders are, but Access/Jet/ACE really only works over SMB networking, not over FTP or HTTP. Anyone expecting anything else really needs to do some homework on understanding Access/Jet/ACE.

Comment: Presumably the Access/Jet/ACE requires some functionality between just read and write, such as locking etc..

Comment: Jet/ACE has a record-locking mechanism, yes. Because it is a file-based database engine, that mechanism is highly coordinated with the file system, and thus doesn't work reliably on anything but native Windows file systems (or well-implemented ports of the Windows file system or SMB networking).

Answer (score 0):

The easy way arround this problem is to use a ODBC DSN to access the database, (BE) and have the FE (front-end), in your local computer. This happens because MS-Access needs to lock the file while using it.

You should be able to work with the FE using SkyDrive and other services like it, cause they copy the file localy, and when you close the file they syncs it to the web folder.